How to customize the name of the organization in the "Sign In With Google" initial page?
In the sign in with Google, the immediate page has a text "Choose an account to continue to something.com". That "something.com" is by default the domain of the authorization server. My question is, is there a way to make that constant like "Something Group Of Companies" instead?
I dont see this option in the standard "Sign In With Google configuration"

This question is similar to: Changing the domain shown by Google Account Chooser. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for your reply @PatrickdC! That i know how to do. But what i'm looking for is a way to NOT used the domain but instead some constant organization name. Is that possible?

I see. So am I correct to assume that you are using firebase to try and fix this issue? (If so, you might as well add the firebase tag on your post. Or are you doing this using Google Cloud Console?

If you are using Google Cloud Console, have you tried going to Navigation Menu > APIs and Services > OAuth Consent Screen and then edit the App Name?

@PatrickdC Im not using firebase. Im using Okta as my primary IDP. And yes under OAuth Consent Screen - i have the organization name set properly, but that name is only being used(it seems) under the Consent page and not on the initial google login page.

When did you make the change? Have you submitted a new request for this change? Based from this post: you need to resubmit the new branding configuration for verification, and receive approval, before the updates take effect on your OAuth consent screen. So I just assume that the changes to the initial google login page will follow afterwards.

Based on that documentation:
"If the app configuration you provide requires verification, you have the opportunity to submit the app for verification. Fill out the required fields and then click Submit to start the verification process.".
In my configuration, the message I'm getting is "Verification not required". With this, how can i submit for brand verification?
